# c# tool sn.exe: with the userlist argument and without the userlist argument

Tags: c#, .net, sn.exe

what is the difference of sn.exe -Vr between with the userlist argument and without the userlist argument?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the userlist argument, the verification skipping applies to those users, without the list it applies to all users.